# Django Static Files on Heroku Dyno

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, heroku, static-files

I am running a django application on Heroku, and currently using AWS S3 to serve my static files. We store our static files both in static folders per app, and also in a `static/` folder at the root of the directory. The `static/` folder at the root is about 40Mb large.

Whenever we deploy our app to Heroku, the static files are included in the Heroku slug, so that
`heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --no-input` can be run from the Dyno itself, which then copies any changed/new static files to our S3 bucket so that they can be served.

The issue is after we go through this process, we now have a `static/` folder on the Dyno which takes up about 40Mb of space, and is seemingly useless since our files are being served from our S3 bucket!

Is there a better way to go about deploying our application, and collecting our static files to our S3 bucket but *not* copying the static files to Heroku?

One way I was thinking was to add all static files to Heroku's .slugignore file, and then configure a way to upload static files to our S3 bucket without using Heroku at all. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to go about it, however, and would appreciate advice on this.

The reason we have been looking into this is our Heroku slug size is starting to grow far too large (~450Mb), and we need to start reducing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more digging, I found examples of people doing exactly what I was describing above, which is uploading static files directly to S3 without using any intermediary storage. [This article](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/) shows how to configure Django and S3 so that running `python manage.py collectstatic` on your local machine will copy the static files directly to S3.

This configuration, in combination with disabling collectstatic on Heroku (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets#disabling-collectstatic) and adding our static files to `.slugignore`, would be exactly what I was looking for, which was to upload static files directly to S3 without uploading them first to Heroku.

More reading from [Django' docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-from-a-cloud-service-or-cdn)